# Bootstrap 3 column with fetch array

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I have the site set up to have 3 columns with image, under the image a title, and under title the description x 3.
If i was to input the words using php all shows fine but when i use the fetch array it breaks the columns and puts each one on a different row. My current code is:

```
        <!-- /.row -->

        <?
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/img/tienda/<? echo $row["images"];?>" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#"><? echo $row["top"];?></a>
                </h3>
                <p><? echo $row["desc"];?></p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will handle the possibility that more than 3 results will be returned by PHP, which would necessitate another row of 1-3 results.  You'd have to add a .clearfix to your CSS that did clear:both which would safely clear the floats contained within the col-md-4.....and besides, it's just good practice to ensure floats don't propagate.

```
    <?
        $inc = 0;  //This is your incrementor
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
           if ($inc == 0) {
    ?>
                <div class="row">
    <?     
           }
    ?>

                     <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                         <a href="#">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src="../link/<? echo $row["images"];?>" alt="">
                         </a>
                         <h3>
                             <a href="#"><? echo $row["top"];?></a>
                         </h3>
                         <p><? echo $row["desc"];?></p>
                    </div>

<?
         if ($inc == 0} {
?>
                   <div class="clearfix"></div>  
            </div>
<?
         }
         $inc = ($inc == 2)? 0 : $inc++;  //Increment unless value = 2, then set to zero   
      } 
?>

        <hr>
```

Comment: thankyou but for some reason something is missing as the page is blank once i added the code

Comment: I found the error and it was here  if ($inc == 0} im getting show up in 1 column only at the moment

Comment: I have seen what you have done and thankyou ever so much for your help. Its really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try

```
        <!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
        <?
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

        <!-- Projects Row -->

            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/img/tienda/<? echo $row["images"];?>" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#"><? echo $row["top"];?></a>
                </h3>
                <p><? echo $row["desc"];?></p>
                </div>

        <!-- /.row -->
        <? } ?>
 </div>
    <hr>
```

Comment: All fine and dandy, but what happens if you have more than 3 results?    You'd want to clear the floats that the columns use and start a new row div.

Comment: @bpeterson76 and how may i do this please?